# Identity in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to get the user's name and ID to be accessible in my view. When I use `Page.User.Identity.Name`, I get the email I use to authenticate it. This is how I go about authenticating the user from my controller:

```
if (!userService.ValidateUser(model.Email, model.Password))
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, false);
```

How can I be able to do: `Page.User.Identity.UserId` or `Page.User.Identity.FirstName`?

Comment: Can you make your question clearer? Because the way it is formed now, it's quite unclear. And BTW which language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but if are using **Identity** in **MVC** and you want to get the User's name and ID in your view I think this will help. In your view try this:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)<br/>
{
    <br/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; @User.Identity.GetUserName() "or" @User.Identity.GetUserId(); <br/>
}
```